# jQuery Datatable not updating the pagination info after filtering

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I have the following code which successfully filters the results of a datatable depending on what is typed into a text input.

```
$('.search-query').keyup(function(e) {
     my_table.fnFilter($(this).val());
});
```

However, this does not alter the pagination info, so despite only showing 3 results it will still say there are 1005 records over 11 pages.

Is there an alternative way to achieve this with the updated pagination?

EDIT:

Here's my code to build the table...

```
my_table = $('.my_table').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "iDisplayLength": 100,
    "iDisplayStart": 0,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sServerMethod": "POST",
    "sAjaxSource": "/get/my/table/data",
    "bSortable": "true",
    "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
    "aaSorting": [],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true},
        { "bSortable": true,},
        { "bSortable": true},
        { "bSortable": true},
        {"bSortable": true},
        {"bSortable": true},
        {"bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true},
    ],
    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": "No Results Found"
    },
    fnDrawCallback: function(){
        if($('.dataTables_paginate ul li').length <= 3)
        {
            $('.dataTables_paginate').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('.dataTables_paginate').show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please setup a JS Fiddle link so it would be helpful to understand your problem, Also specify which version you are using. The latest version might solve this type of issue.

Comment: check to see if that filter happens then tr's gets removed or it just hide. if hide then the behavior is correct.

Comment: Are you using Datatable's pagination or it is custom written?

Comment: @Jai The tr's are being removed.

Comment: What version of dataTables? I highly suspect this issue to have to do with the serverside settings. Try to upgrade.

Comment: @Bhavesh, OP cannot create a jsFiddle reproducing the problem, since he is using `sServerMethod : POST` (illegal in jsFiddle) and ajax source for data. Here is the same code using clientside data, this works -> http://jsfiddle.net/JBy76/

Comment: @davidkonrad - Thanks for creating that fiddle, - is there a way to make mine work given that I'm getting the data serverside?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating table using

```
$('.search-query').keyup(function(e) {
    my_table.fnFilter($(this).val()).fnUpdate({});
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work... I think the problem is caused as a result of loading the data via ajax.